# Require vs refer to JS script in Electron's render process

Tags: node.js, performance, electron

I'm new to Electron. I'm writting an application that uses several client-side UI library, such as jQuery, mask-plugin and d3.js.

Considering perfomance, I would like to know if there is any difference between requireing a JS library in the Renderer process instead of directly refering in a script src tag. Precisely, are require calls more costly than simple scripts src tag in the Render process?

For instance (a very minimal and simple example), which one is faster?

```
<script>
    "use strict"

    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.Tether = require('tether');
    window.Bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
    require("jquery-validation");
</script>
```

or refer to the min script directly in the src tag:

```
<script src="js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/core/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, require doesn't download anything. The script is already locally installed in your node_modules folder. So they're both fetching the local script. require does things behind the scenes, but I'm not well acquainted with what that is. I don't imagine that the fact that you're using Electron really makes this any different from any other Node app. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132130/whats-the-difference-between-using-require-in-node-console-and-use-script-tag-i) has some information, though maybe it's not totally pertinent to what you need

Comment: Also see [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-script-tag-with-src-and-a-script-tag-that-requires-a-module)

Comment: They are negligible. What type of module bundler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of taste and style than performance I believe. For me personally, I prefer to call libraries from code with require (or import in newer JS) than to add additional scripts to the page.

This allows me to have better visibility of what is being called when working on the code, rather than jumping from source to view.